# Sharepoint list column type person

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, power-automate, sharepoint-list

I hope you can help me, I have a sharepoint list, I have a person type column, but I would like to extract the data it has (email, name) and place it as a text type in another column so that when the person type field is changed it also modifies these two but I tried to do it with a calculated column, but I think it is not supported, do you have any idea how to do this type of change.

Thanks

Comment: Use the Get User Profile Power Automate action

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it using JSON column formatting code like below:

```
{

"$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
"elmType": "div",
"txtContent": {
        "operator": "+",
        "operands": [
            "mail: ",
            "[$person.email]",
            " name: ",
            "[$person.title]"
        ]
    }
```

}

[image]